# How do I convert Gitpod's Root url to https?

Tags: laravel, httprequest, remote-access, gitpod

I'm using Gitpod for my laravel application. Although the frontend is working perfectly, I cannot save data to my mysql database(gives me 405 method error whenever I signup). I tried to investigate this issue and found out that Gitpod is using "http" for submitting my form. But the client's URL is in https `(https://8000-*****.gitpod.io/)`. How do I change the form submission action to "https" so it would match the URL?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a repository or snapshot (https://www.gitpod.io/docs/sharing-and-collaboration/#sharing-snapshots)?

Comment: @SvenEfftinge https://gitpod.io#snapshot/d8a80080-1e05-413e-9402-034656bd204f

Comment: @SvenEfftinge I can also share my running workspace if you want to. I've been trying to fix this for hours now.

Comment: I don't know how to initialize your database. So I'm getting 500 from the server because of missing tables. Could we move conversation over to community.gitpod.io it's easier to chat there.